# How to sort std::set of indices according to the vector of sorted indices?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, gcc8

I have a class `MyClass`, which operates with some double values `beta`, stored as a class member, in it's member function `g`. It sorts them and stores the permutation in the class member `std::vector<int> sorted_beta_ind`:

```
double MyClass::g() {
  // ...
  sorted_beta_ind.resize(n);
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    sorted_beta_ind[i] = i;
  }
  std::sort(sorted_beta_ind.begin(), sorted_beta_ind.end(),
            [this] (const int &a, const int &b) {++op_cmp; return beta[a] > beta[b];});
  // ...
}
```

Next I want to have several ordered sets of indices in another member function `f`, which will store the indices in the same order as in `sorted_beta_ind`. I'm trying to use `std::set` objects, and as such, I need a comparator. The best solution I figured out is a lambda function

```
double MyClass::f() {
  auto ind_comp = [&order = sorted_beta_ind] (const int &a, const int &b) {
    int pos_a = ~0, pos_b = ~0;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<order.size(); ++i) {
      if(order[i] == a) {
        pos_a = i;
      }
      if(order[i] == b) {
        pos_b = i;
      }
    }
    return pos_a < pos_b;
  };
  std::set<int, decltype(ind_comp)> d0, d1;
  // the rest of the function which uses std::union and std::instersection
}
```

but on building the project I get

```
error: use of deleted function ‘MyClass::f()::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>& MyClass::f(int**, int)::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>::operator=(const MyClass::f()::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>&)’
```

Can this approach work or I should try something entirely else?

Comment: If you want the sets to contain indices sorted in the same order as in the vector, why not use the same comparison functor? [example](https://godbolt.org/z/gp3iBZ) What are you using the set of indices for? Won't a `map<index, object>` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capturing lambda expressions, like yours, are not *DefaultConstructible*. And that's exactly what `std::set` tries to do unless it receives a comparator object  that can be copied from as a constructor call argument. That is:

```
std::set<int, decltype(ind_comp)> d0, d1;
```

Here `std::set` knows only the type of the comparator, and will attempt to constuct one using its default constructor. Instead, it should be:

```
std::set<int, decltype(ind_comp)> d0(ind_comp), d1(ind_comp);
//                                   ~~~~~~~^      ~~~~~~~^
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if I want to use something like `std::set<int, decltype(ind_comp)> d0[2];`, i.e. arrays of sets?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat tried building using C++20, no luck, the error persists.

Comment: @Verloren Nevermind, didn't notice your lambda had captures. PiotrSkotnicki, yep, my bad.

Comment: @Verloren This array again performs *default* initialization of both sets. You need to specify both elements, e.g., `using S = std::set<int, decltype(ind_comp)>; S d[2]{ S(ind_comp), S(ind_comp) };`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Did what you proposed but the error is still there.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki `stl_tree.h:1740:27: error: use of deleted function ‘MyClass::f()::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>& MyClass::f()::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>::operator=(const MyClass::f()::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>&)’
    _M_impl._M_key_compare = __x._M_impl._M_key_compare;
MyClass.cpp:176:43: note: a lambda closure type has a deleted copy assignment operator
   auto ind_comp = [&temp = sorted_beta_ind] (const int &a, const int &b) {
`

Comment: Not that line :) But I guess that most likely you eventually try to copy-assign one set to another, do you ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki The only line that copies something goes like this: `auto &temp_set = cond ? d1 : d0;`, where I'm only trying to pick a reference to a set based on a condition and not to copy the entire set.

Comment: The error message for sure goes on to say "required from" and gives the line number in the code that attempts to copy-assign the lambda expression

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki it points to lines inside "std_set.h" and "stl_tree.h", not my code.

Comment: @Verloren It eventually should point at your code. You're not showing the full code, so I can't tell what's wrong. [It compiles](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1uS4sZ5dHiQ9TzWv)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Nevermind, I missed another line that showed to be the culprit. Thank you for your help!